# "Groups UpdateGroupAsAdmin" API throws 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: powerbi-rest-api

I'm using [Admin - Groups UpdateGroupAsAdmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/groups-update-group-as-admin) API to update description of the workspace.

Workspace access is configured: service principle, which I use to authenticate API, is set as Admin for my workspace (also as described in this thread [Unable to patch reportgroup name with a service principal account](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Developer/Unable-to-patch-reportgroup-name-with-a-service-principal/m-p/2912492#M39793)).

But when I run "Groups UpdateGroupAsAdmin" request either from my C# code or from Postman, I receive 401 Unauthorized error.

Are the needed some specific rights to be set for service principle to execute this PATCH query?

Thank you very much in advance.